# How can get the custom addons path in odoo by code

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

The custom module I'm Working on Requires to Write Some files to the odoo `addons` path. Can anybody Tell me How to get the `addons` path by code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the addons path from the code like this,

```
import odoo.tools as tools

path = tools.config.get('addons_path')
```